# How would I reverse this? Python 3.8

Tags: python, math, encryption

So I've created a very... odd little caesar cipher using python. Very simple. Except, I'm not really all that great at math and am wondering how I'd reverse this?

```
def encrypt(text,s): 
    result = "" 
    for i in range(len(text)): 
        char = text[i] 
        if (char.isupper()): 
            result += chr((ord(char) + s - 23+213**3) % 26 + 713) 
        else: 
            result += chr((ord(char) + s - 23+213**3) % 26 + 715) 
    return result 

text = input("Message: ")
s = 964

print ("Text: " + text) 
print ("Shift: " + str(s)) 
print ("Cipher: " + encrypt(text,s))
```

Any form of help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I'M SO CLOSE!
I did that math as to how the shift works:

if the letter is a capital:
 1. `964 - 23+213^3, which ends up as -9662656`
 2. `Get the remainder of that divided by 26 (modulo operator) -9662656 % 26 = 10`
 3. `10 + 714 = 724`
 4. `724-63` I got the 63 just through trial and error...

ONLY PROBLEM!
It all works up until the letter M, in which case the last 13 letters shift backward 26 characters. How would I solve this?

```
def decrypt(text,s): 
    result = "" 
    for i in range(len(text)): 
        char = text[i] 
        result += chr((ord(char) - s))
    return result 

text = input("Message: ")
s = 724-63

print ("Text: " + text) 
print ("Shift: " + str(s)) 
print ("Cipher: " + decrypt(text,s))
```

```
Text: ˖˗˘˙˚˛˜˝˞˟ˠˡˢˉˊˋˌˍˎˏːˑ˒˓˔˕
Shift: 661
Cipher: ABCDEFGHIJKLM456789:;<=>?@
```

Comment: Why do you have the conditional `if (char.isupper()):` if both have the same update for result?

Comment: I am no math expert but I do believe that the modulus operator is going to make deciphering difficult. Look at it this way, everything on the left side of the modulus operator will be squished down to a value between 0-25. This effectively mean that your output will always be between 715-740 for each character. How will this work for numbers, lower case and upper case values?  As you can see, you will have many collisions.

Comment: Encryption has to be a one-to-one mapping if it is to be decrypted successfully.  Modulo is a many-to-one mapping so there are always many possible answers when decrypting.  What you have is more like a hash function than an encryption.

Comment: As @rossum notes, you cannot uniquely decrypt if your alphabet is greater than 26 symbols. The modulus must be at least as big as your alphabet. But you can decrypt if you restrict your input to 26 symbols, for example only uppercase ASCII letters. Or, if you make your modulus 52 then you can operate on upper and lower case ASCII letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your encrypt function to show the individual piece of the calculation. Then I wrote the decrypt function to show how to "undo" them.

Note that -23+213<sup>3</sup> is equivalent to 24 when working mod 26.

```py
def encrypt(text, s):
    cipher = ""
    for pt_char in text:
        val = ord(pt_char)          # 65 <= val < 91
        t0 = val % 26               # 0 <= t0 < 26, with A=>13, B=>14, ... N=>0 etc.
        t1 = (t0 + s + 24) % 26     # 0 <= t1 < 26
        t2 = t1 + 715               # 715 <= t2 < 741
        cipher += chr(t2)
    return cipher


def decrypt(ct, s):
    plain = ""
    for ct_char in ct:
        t2 = ord(ct_char)           # 715 <= t2 < 741
        t1 = t2 - 715               # 0 <= t1 < 26
        t0 = (t1 - s - 24 + 13) % 26     # 0 <= t0 < 26
        val = t0 + 65               # 65 <= val < 91
        plain += chr(val)
    return plain
```

Again, this only works for upper case ASCII letters. Pay attention to the comments, they are telling you something.

Here are shorter one-liner just to show you something about how generators can produce compact code.

```py
def encrypt_one_liner(text, s):
    return ''.join(chr((ord(x) + s + 24) % 26 + 715) for x in text)


def decrypt_one_liner(text, s):
    return ''.join(chr((ord(x) + 2 - s) % 26 + 65) for x in text)
```

Comment: That's awesome! So Python doesn't exactly calculate the brackets involved with -23+213^3 correctly? When Dad and I tried just printing the equation (with slightly different methods each time) we couldn't get 24. What did you do to get it?

Comment: I don't know if python calculates it, though I suspect it does. It's just that -23 + 213\**3 is mathematically equivalent to 24 mod 26.